# Import Model from another app with the same name as the current App

Tags: python, django

This is the trimmed version of my Environment App;

```
from belongings.models import Item

class Achievement(models.Model):

    sub_category = models.ForeignKey('AchievementSubcategory')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 45)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True)
    points = models.IntegerField() # The amount of points rewarded for the achievement
    rewarded_item = models.ForeignKey('belongings.Item', blank = True, null = True, default = None)
```

No I'm doing this schemamigration;

```
 python manage.py schemamigration environment --auto
```

..and it gives me;

```
 ImportError: cannot import name Element
```

The probable reason this happens is because Element is linked as a ForeignKey in `belongings.Item`.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Since you are doing `'belongings.Item'` you dont need the import at the top

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you have a circular import.

You've partially dealt with it by using string foreign key references (`'belongings.Item'`). Now you still need to remove the actual python import to get rid of the circular reference.

Remove this:

```
from belongings.models import Item
```